Is Managed code with DirectX Distributed with Product Code
I am trying to understand the distribution terms for the Managed DirectX libraries. I am particularly looking for information on whether these libraries are distributed alongside the product code or  if they require a separate licensing agreement. Additionally, I am unable to find any current resources on the official website regarding these libraries. Can anyone clarify where I can access these libraries for development purposes or how to find the distribution terms for Managed code for DirectX?
These are libraries which are being used

Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPIayback.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.Diagnostics.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectDraw.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectPIay.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dII
Microsoft.DirectX.dII

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The official way to install it is to run the "DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35 and that's about it, the license comes with it. Note it will only install them if .NET Framework 1 => 3.5 is installed. These are totally legacy (20+ years) components never updated that no one should use for new projects, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_DirectX
